# Allowing custom domain names for tenants on multi tenant SaaS platform hosted on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, domain-mapping

**Overview**

I am building a multi tenant SaaS platform on AWS. The deployment architecture for now is very simple.

- I have a ELB (all traffic falls here)
- I have few EC2 instances (hosting my java + angular application). This is under a Autoscaling group which is linked to the ELB.
- I have a MySQL cluster in RDS which the EC2 talks to.

Everything is in a VPC and the EC2 and RDS are in private subnets,

**Problem**

I would prefer my clients (tenants) to have their own domain name. For e.g. Let's say that right now my application is accessible at the URL http://xyz-elb.amazon.aws.com

I would like to enable my clients to access the application using

- http://tenant1.com
- http://tenant2.com

  and so one. I know this is possible because I have seen this in different multi tenant SaaS applications.

**Research I have done till now:**
I read about reverse proxy which can accomplish it however, I didn't get any reliable link. Tried reading about HAProxy but I feel that I am going in the wrong direction.

**What I need**

- Expert opinion on different ways to do domain mapping
- List & Link of resources which address this particular problem
- Any practical experience or case studies by any of you cool guys here
- A cheap solution (I don't want to go via Amazon API Gateway / Route53 Policies which doesn't seem to fit my need)

Thank you so much for reading my question. And thanks in advance for your efforts to reply on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a DNS CNAME resource record in each tenant domain, pointing to your apps ELB DNS name.

I prefer to alias the ELB DNS name to my service domain,  then alias the tenant domain to it. Example:

> app.example.com IN CNAME my-loadbalancer-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com

Then in my tenant DNS:

> app.tenant1.com IN CNAME app.example.com.

This aliasing allows you to change your ELB endpoint if required, without having to change the DNS records for all clients.